# How to obtain the stacktrace and error message from MSTest run?

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, mstest

When I've used NUnit 3.x, I've been able to obtain both stack trace and error message using the following in my `[TearDown]` function:

```
var stackTrace = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace;
var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
```

Therefore, if I add an exception message to my assertion (i.e. `Assert.AreEqual("A", "B", "A is not equal to B");`, I can access that error message and input it into my report via the `var errorMessage` variable above.

I've yet to find a comparable way to access these values in MSTest, and the `TestContext` variable for my tests do not seem to contain any accessible values related to these messages outside of checking if the test passed or failed via `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome`.

Is there a way to obtain this information from MSTest runs?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Exception` class and capturing the results from that?  Also, are you decorating your tests with the `[ExpectedException(typeof(SomeExceptionHere))]` attribute?

Comment: @Brian I have implemented your suggestion of decorating my tests with the `ExpectedException` annotation. My question now is, I am utilizing third party reporting to generate an HTML report of my test runs, so how would I then capture the exception messages so I can utilize them in the report?

Comment: Are you using `try/catch` blocks?  Can you write the stack trace using the third party reporting tool?  I suppose I really would need to see the code for one of your tests to make a more educated suggestion.  Can you post one?

Comment: Is using MSTest v2 an option? You can author your own `ITestMethod` implementation, catch failures and report as required.

More info and sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/RFCs/003-Customize-Running-Tests.md

Comment: Keith i'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution for that?